# SFML app runs form Code::Blocks but not standalone

Tags: c++, sfml

I have followed the official [tutorial](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/start-cb.php/%20%22tutorial%22r). It works but not stadalone (pops out messagebox saying that .exe has stopped working). 
Any ideas what could have gone wrong?

Comment: I think You'll need to copy SFML `.dll` files to Your `.exe` file directory.

Comment: @Jacajack that's not the problem, All .dlls are included. :<

Comment: Are You sure they all are in standalone `exe` file directory?

Comment: @Jacajack Yep. It woud give error that `dll` is missing though.

Comment: Remember that if You're using sound in Your app You need also to copy `openal32.dll`

Comment: @Jacajack I actually included all dlls, even not used.

Comment: Hmm... That's weird... Maybe if You try running it from `cmd.exe` it'll tell You what's missing